# Ethernet socket

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I can't get my socket to receive any data even though I know data is showing up at the Ethernet port.  Socket creation and binding are successful.  But it just sits forever in `recvfrom()`.  At my wits end so I beg for your help!  Here's my socket-related code (retyped, not copy/pasted so possible typos):

```
#define MTU 1500

struct sockaddr_in LocalEndPoint;
struct sockaddr_in RemoteEndPoint;

int socketHandle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

if(socketHandle == -1)
   printf("Error 1");
else
   printf("Socket created");

memset((char*)&LocalEndPoint, 0, sizeof(LocalEndPoint));
LocalEndPoint.sin_family = AF_INET;
LocalEndPoint.sin_port = htons(51610);
LocalEndPoint.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

int bind_ret_val = bind(socketHandle, (sockaddr*)&LocalEndPoint, sizeof(LocalEndPoint)) < 0;

if(bind_ret_val < 0)
   printf("Error 2");
else
   printf("Bound");

char* buffer = new char[MTU];
unsigned int msg_length;
socklen_t addressSize0 = sizeof(RemoteEndPoint);

printf("Waiting for packet");
msg_length = recvfrom(socketHandle, buffer, MTU, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&RemoteEndPoint, &addressSize0);
printf("Packet received");
```

I have a camera connected that is streaming UDP packets.  I confirm with an in-line Ethernet sniffer that the camera is sending packets with the following info, which seems to match my Ethernet adapter and socket configuration perfectly.

```
source MAC = 70:B3:D5:EA:E3:11
destination MAC = 00:1F:7B:B4:1F:11
source IP = 192.168.40.61
destination IP = 192.168.40.11
source port = 51610
destination port = 51610
```

I also confirm with the ifconfig command that the `eth0` adapter in my receiving [Linux] machine that packets are being seen by the adapter because `ifconfig` gives a packet count for "RX packets" and it is steadily increasing with the stream.

Comment: I find `netcat` (also known as `nc`) is great for debugging this type of stuff.

Comment: try to do tcpdump on your Linux machine to be sure that you get these packets.

Comment: Check your firewall settings to see if port 51610 is blocked (e.g. iptables -nL | grep 51610).

Comment: @MarkSetchell with ifconfig I see packets arriving at the network adapter.  In wireshark (on a separate computer), I see packets coming on port 51610.  But netcat does not see anything on port 51610.

Comment: On Ubuntu I needed to open the port using `ufw`. By default I think all ports above 1024 need to be opened manually.

Comment: May be it is not related to your problem but the check for bind return value is wrong. `bind_ret_val = bind(...) < 0;` assigns `0` or `1` to `bind_ret_val` according to the result. But it is newer less than zero and `Bound` is printed even if `bind()` fails.